# Can't Install CentOS 6.4 from USB

Tags: linux, installation, centos

Cannot install Cent OS on a box I build up.
Here are the log entries visible on the screen:

```
sd 0:0:0:0 [sda] Write ache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA 
sda: sda1
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
dracut Warning: No root device "block:/dev/mapper/live-rw" found
dracut Warning: Boot has failed. To debug this issue add "rdshell" to the kernel command line.
dracut Warning: Signal caught!
dracut Warning: Boot fas failed. To debug this issue add "rdshell" to the kernel command line.
Kernel pnaic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
Pid: 1, comm: init Tainted: G   --------- H 2.6.32-358.e16.x86_64
```

**Installation Medium:**

- 16GB USB 3.0
- Fat32
- Installed CentOS-6.4-x86_64-LiveDVD.iso using unetbootin-windows-585.

**Hardware:**

- MSI motherboard H87-G43 (LGA 1150)
- i5-4430 Haswell
- 8 GB DDR3

There is also a SATA drive connected to the machine. It has some old Windows OS installed on it when it was part of a laptop. I want to reformat that drive and use it as the primary hard drive for the Linux install.

My Linux knowledge is basic admin stuff. My goal is to build this box so I can install some IBM product and ultimate write an app.

**Please advise.**

Comment: Have a look at http://pendrivelinux.com

Answer (score 2):

When I have trouble with media created with unetbootin, I try using [LinuxLive](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) instead.

(Ironically, when I have trouble with LinuxLive, I try to use unetbootin)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not iso2usb, unetbootin, LinuxLive or another of the utilities to create bootable media. The problem was in CentOS or perhaps the relationship between CentOS and my particular hardware. I tried the Ubuntu distro and it worked on the first try.

Answer (score 0):

Might be that the USB drive creation tool is installing GRUB2 which cannot boot CentOS 6.4

Ensure that your USB creation tool installs plain GRUB when it pushes the ISO to the USB drive.